# How is the class method syntax programmed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yield, higher-order-functions

NOTE: Sorry, I originally thought this was React specific syntax because I am new to the ES6 class syntax.

My original question stands: 
How do you generate a method like `render() {}` outside of the ES6 class?
What is going on under the hood that allows this syntax inside classes but not outside?

To clarify--- this is a normal function:

```
function myMethod() {console.log('yay')}
myMethod() // ---> yay
```

However if you define a func like a React lifecycle method--- `myMethod() {console.log('boo')}` ---
it produces a syntax error, `unexpected token {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188307/discussion-between-guest271314-and-jeremy-gottfried).

Answer (score 1):

> How do you generate a method that can be called like `render() {}`

That is not possible. The line `render() {}` is a function definition.

In react, you are defining methods such as `componentDidMount` and `render`. These are methods that React lib expects a component to have. React will then call those methods at certain times throughout the component lifecycle. That is why they are called `lifecycle` methods.